# SUID not working?

Tags: command-line, bash, uid

On Ubuntu 16.04.1:

`test.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IAM=$(whoami)
ID=$(id -u $IAM)
echo "${IAM}"
echo "${ID}"


Andromeda $ ls -al | grep test.sh 
-rwsrwxrwx  1 pkaramol pkaramol        71 Δεκ   8 07:52 test.sh
```

As `pkaramol` (`uid`=1000)

```
Andromeda $ ./test.sh 
pkaramol
1000
```

As `testuser` (`uid`=1001)

```
Andromeda $ su testuser 
Password: 
testuser@Andromeda:/home/pkaramol/Desktop$ ./test.sh 
testuser
1001
```

Given that the `suid` has been set, why, in the second run, do we not see `pkaramol` and `1000` in the output? Isn't the script supposed to be executed with the file owner's id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 2 execve`, section NOTES](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/execve.2.html):

```
Linux ignores the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits on scripts.
```

Also see:

- [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364/70524)